# Travis CI with 14.04/Indigo and/or alternatives

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking into continuous integration options, the obvious one is Travis CI. To my dismay I quickly discovered that it is really easy to use, but unfortunately the offered servers only run Ubuntu 12.04, so builds requiring Indigo/14.04 are not easily possible. There is a new Docker-based build environment in place ([description here](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-12-17-faster-builds-with-container-based-infrastructure/)), but the limitation of not allowing running `sudo` makes things very complicated.

My questions thus are: Are there any solutions out there that make it possible to run 14.04/Indigo with Travis? How do other current options for CI compare to Travis? What I especially like about Travis is the fact that no (server) infrastructure has to be maintained by the user.

/edit: Just came across this question: [drone.io instead of travis](http://answers.ros.org/question/210507/droneio-instead-of-travis/). Certainly sounds like an alternative, but no instructions for use with 14.04 so far either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215724/travis-ci-with-14.04/indigo-and/or-alternatives/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of mid-October Travis [supports Ubuntu 14.04 trusty](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-10-14-opening-up-ubuntu-trusty-beta/)! I've been running travis with ROS indigo without any problems.

To get running in a [trusty build environment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment/), you simply have to add the following to your .travis.yml file:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) with karma: 539 on 2015-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2